Is it possible to have a distinguishable tap gesture for a List or ScrollView background?
I have this view hierarchy:
let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

var body: some View {

    ZStack {

        Color.green
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Background tapped!")
            }

        List {

            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in

                HStack {

                    Text(item)

                    Spacer()

                    Button(action: {
                        print("Item action: \(item) was tapped")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Click Me!")
                    })
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                }
                .listRowBackground(EmptyView())
            }

        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("List tapped!")
        }
    }
}

Where I have a backgroundView with some color behind a scrollable List with a number of rows,  these rows have buttons inside.
I'm trying to make the .onTapGesture on Color.green work when I tap anywhere outside the rows, but it is never called.
I also tried to add onTapGesture to the List itself, but the problem is this gesture is called in parallel when I tap any button inside the rows.
Current Output:

Tapping in area 1 (Ok):
List tapped!

Tapping in area 2 (Ok):
List tapped!

Tapping in area 3 (Not Ok):
Item action: Item 3 was tapped
List tapped!

I'm trying to make tapping in 3 calling ONLY the Item action and not the List.
Any clues or workarounds? Your help is appreciated.
I tried to add
.allowsHitTesting(false) to the List and / or to the Rows, which allowed calling the Color.green, but stopped recognizing the Row's actions.
Same for
.contentShape(EmptyShape()) which is basically
struct EmptyShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path()
    }
}


You could use this
ScrollView { ... }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) instead of a List.
Alternatively, try using LazyVStack instead of a List.

Sadly, there is a huge performance difference, I can't drop the List
